# How to get specific values from a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, slice, key-value

Could you help me getting the specific values I wanted in the below list

```
list=[['Russia',[{'id': 250282,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1796,'value': 'silver'},
                {'id': 250212,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1896,'value': 'gold'},
                {'id': 250242,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1396,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 250082,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1496,'value': 'cobalt'}]],
      ['China',[{'id': 210282,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1196,'value': 'silver'},
                {'id': 220212,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1396,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 240242,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1586,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 250082,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1492,'value': 'gold'}]],
      ['Africa',[]],
      ['USA',[{'id': 200282,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1093,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 253212,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1843,'value': 'gold'},
                {'id': 255242,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1323,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 257082,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1409,'value': 'cobalt'}]],
      ['UK',[]]]


output should be:
  'Russia', 19553
  'China',  193
  'Africa', 0  
  'USA',    5531
  'UK',     0
```

I am trying to get countries and unique values of d_id because it will be the same for all records and impute missing values with 0

I tried for loops and slicing of lists but nothing worked out
If anyone of you have a solution for this that would be much appreciated.

output should be:
'Russia', 19553
'China',  193
'Africa', 0
'USA',    5531
'UK',     0

In the above output Africa and UK d_id values are imputed with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in list:
    country = item[0]
    metal = item[1]
    d_id = []
    for details in metal:
        for ids in details:
            if ids == 'd_id':
                d_id.append(details[ids])
    d_id = set(d_id)

if len(d_id):
    print(f"{country},{d_id}")
else:
    print(f"{country},0")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Next time you should include the code that you've tried with your question.

`{l[0]: set([_d['d_id'] for _d in l[1]]) if len(l[1]) > 0 else set([0]) for l in your_list}`

Answer (score 0):

Your inner lists have 2 values - a country name and a list of records. You could iterate the list, using tuple expansion to get those two values. If the list of records is not empty, grab the first value, otherwise use zero.

```
list=[['Russia',[{'id': 250282,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1796,'value': 'silver'},
                {'id': 250212,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1896,'value': 'gold'},
                {'id': 250242,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1396,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 250082,'d_id': 19553,'p_id': 1496,'value': 'cobalt'}]],
      ['China',[{'id': 210282,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1196,'value': 'silver'},
                {'id': 220212,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1396,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 240242,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1586,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 250082,'d_id': 193,'p_id': 1492,'value': 'gold'}]],
      ['Africa',[]],
      ['USA',[{'id': 200282,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1093,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 253212,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1843,'value': 'gold'},
                {'id': 255242,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1323,'value': 'iron'},
                {'id': 257082,'d_id': 5531,'p_id': 1409,'value': 'cobalt'}]],
      ['UK',[]]]


output = []
for name, records in list:
    if records:
        d_id = records[0]['d_id']
    else:
        d_id = 0
    output.append((name, d_id))

for name, d_id in output:
    print(f"    '{name}': {d_id}")
```